# Could not find installstate error while executing InstallerClass's Roolback event in setup project

Tags: c#, setup-project, custom-action, uninstallation

I have created a Visual Studio setup project and added two console applications as project output to the setup project. Each Console app has its installerclass. In the Setup Project's Custom Action I have added above two applications.

In the consoleApp2's InstallerClass I have some validations , if the validations are successful then it will validate ConsoleApp1's InstallerClass, else setup installation should be rollbacked.

During rollback operation, I am getting "Error 1001. Could not find file app path\Consoleapp1.InstallState" as below, as it's installstate is not yet initiated.

[image]

Is there any way to fix this issue. My main motto is to rollback the installation  without errors disaplayed to the user if the validations in installerclass fail. Below is the code I am using.

```
  public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
    {
        base.Install(stateSaver);
        MessageBox.Show("Install");
        try
        {
            const string subkey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\";

            using (RegistryKey ndpKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32).OpenSubKey(subkey))
            {
                if (ndpKey != null && ndpKey.GetValue("Release") != null && Convert.ToInt32(ndpKey.GetValue("Release")) > 461310)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Framework version is " + ndpKey.GetValue("Release").ToString());

                    string message = "This setup requires .Net framework Version 4.7.1. Please install the .Net Framework and run setup again. The .Net framework can be  obtained from the web. Would you like to do this now ?";
                    MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
                    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(message, "", buttons);
                    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        Process.Start("http://go.microsoft.com");

                        throw new InstallException(String.Format("Installation rollbacked."));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new InstallException(String.Format("Cancelling Installation"));

                    }

                }
                else
                {


                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new Exception(String.Format("Cancelling Installation 123"));

        }

    }
    public override void Rollback(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        base.Rollback(savedState);
        MessageBox.Show("rollback c2 " + savedState.Values);
    }
    public override void Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        base.Uninstall(savedState);
    }
    public override void Commit(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        base.Commit(savedState);
    }
```